# SQLAlchemy combined joins

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to filter last 200 games where both teams are tennis players (`Team.tennisplayer_id` is not `None`) and both players have day of birth stored in the database, ie `dayOfBirth is not None`

I tried:

```
limit = 200
with app.app_context():
     games = db.session.query(Game).filter(Game.time_started!=None, Game.scores_home!=None, Game.scores_away!=None).join(Team, Game.team_home_id==Team.id).join(Team, Game.team_away_id==Team.id).filter(Team.tennisplayer_id!=None).join(TennisPlayer, Team.tennisplayer_id==TennisPlayer.id).filter(TennisPlayer.dayOfBirth!=None).order_by(desc(Game.time_started)).limit(limit).all()
```

but I'm getting `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1066, "Not unique table/alias: 'team'")`

Could you guys help me with this please?

```
class Game (db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    scores_home = db.Column(db.Integer)
    scores_away = db.Column(db.Integer)
    
    team_home_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("team.id"), index=True)
    team_home = relationship("Team", foreign_keys=[team_home_id], lazy='joined')

    team_away_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("team.id"), index=True)
    team_away = relationship("Team", foreign_keys=[team_away_id], lazy='joined')
    
    time_started = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    
class Team (db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    
    tennisplayer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("tennis_player.id"))
    tennisplayer = relationship("TennisPlayer", lazy='joined')
        

class TennisPlayer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tennis_player'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    
    dayOfBirth = db.Column(db.DateTime)     
    
    teams = relationship("Team", back_populates="tennisplayer")
```

Answer (score 0):

using **aliased()** seems to work:

```
limit = 200
with app.app_context():

    TeamHome = aliased(Team)
    TeamAway = aliased(Team)

    TennisPlayerHome = aliased(TennisPlayer)
    TennisPlayerAway = aliased(TennisPlayer)

     games = db.session.query(Game)\
            .filter(Game.time_started!=None, Game.scores_home!=None, Game.scores_away!=None)\
            .join(TeamHome, Game.team_home_id==TeamHome.id)\
            .join(TeamAway, Game.team_away_id==TeamAway.id)\
            .filter(TeamHome.tennisplayer_id!=None, TeamAway.tennisplayer_id!=None)\
            .join(TennisPlayerHome,TeamHome.tennisplayer_id==TennisPlayerHome.id)\
            .join(TennisPlayerAway,TeamAway.tennisplayer_id==TennisPlayerAway.id)\
            .filter(TennisPlayerHome.dayOfBirth!=None, TennisPlayerAway.dayOfBirth!=None)\
            .order_by(desc(Game.time_started)).limit(limit).all()
```